# Large increase in joint significance when introducing robust covariance matrix estimator

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, robust-standard-error

I have a linear regression model where $Y$ is regressed on five dummies $X_3,X_4,X_5,X_{10},X_{20}$. (In R, I actually regress $Y$ on a factor $X$ that produces the 5 dummies.) My sample size is 24 (plus 6 `NA` observations).

When I naively test the joint significance of the dummies, the $p$-value is `0.4124`. When I introduce heteroskedasticity-robust covariance matrix, I get a $p$-value of `0.003324`. A change in significance of this magnitude seems fishy to me. What am I missing?

(Note that the individual regressors become less significant upon the introduction of the heteroskedasticity-robust standard errors, something I find intuitive. At the same time, this makes the huge increase in the joint significance even more puzzling.)

````r
> dput(y)
c(-0.0151021101926254, -0.0309851953937721, 0.0114773798796626, 
-0.0239734402153541, 0.0676350205999363, 0.0228620593817569, 
NA, NA, -0.0475378138063825, 0.0646450541679466, NA, -0.00520255289479559, 
0.0405746527075472, 0.0178849404415307, -0.00874351591122196, 
-0.0544415483370128, 0.0946388458623007, 0.0101295037685308, 
0.0171868062386878, -0.00259921472353685, -0.0479843871962202, 
0.0107363946469932, 0.00597028176762957, -0.0214522363058097, 
NA, -0.0270221434281566, NA, 0.0338132549609079, 0.112261926884369, 
NA)
> dput(x)
structure(c(4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 
1L), levels = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "7", "10", "20"), class = "factor")
> 
> packages=c("car","lmtest","sandwich")
> for(package in packages) library(package,character.only=TRUE)
> 
> m2=lm(y~x); summary(m2)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.094049 -0.022485 -0.005668  0.018662  0.072655 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  0.039607   0.021498   1.842   0.0820 .
x3          -0.064899   0.037236  -1.743   0.0984 .
x4          -0.042783   0.027754  -1.541   0.1406  
x5          -0.039041   0.026330  -1.483   0.1554  
x10         -0.007062   0.032839  -0.215   0.8322  
x20         -0.005794   0.048072  -0.121   0.9054  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.043 on 18 degrees of freedom
  (6 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.2281,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.01368 
F-statistic: 1.064 on 5 and 18 DF,  p-value: 0.4124

> vcov2=vcovHC(m2,type="HC1")
> print(coeftest(m2,vcov.=vcov2))

t test of coefficients:

              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.0396074  0.0390340  1.0147   0.3237
x3          -0.0648992  0.0432082 -1.5020   0.1504
x4          -0.0427830  0.0426467 -1.0032   0.3291
x5          -0.0390411  0.0401830 -0.9716   0.3441
x10         -0.0070618  0.0420075 -0.1681   0.8684
x20         -0.0057941  0.0390340 -0.1484   0.8836

> hypo=paste0(names(coef(m2))[-1],"=0")
> lh2=linearHypothesis(model=m2, hypothesis.matrix=hypo, rhs=NULL, vcov.=vcov2); print(lh2)
Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
x3 = 0
x4 = 0
x5 = 0
x10 = 0
x20 = 0

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: y ~ x

Note: Coefficient covariance matrix supplied.

  Res.Df Df     F   Pr(>F)   
1     23                     
2     18  5 5.397 0.003324 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```
````

Comment: In a similar vein, see also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/643411

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but common sense tells me that if you would like to correct for heteroscedasticity across different groups, there should be variance in each group. But in group x=20 there is none. The error is zero here, and I do not see how such an observation could generate heteroscedasticity. So this could be a problem for any of the methods HC0, HC1, HC..., while actually it is no problem because it makes more sense to me to investigate heteroscedasticity without this observation anyway. I would probably check what happens if you add a few fake data points for x=20, or if you would remove it. I did the last option and then the final test is INsignificant, as one would expect, p=0.17. With HC3 it's even less significant 0.46 if I remember well. (With x=20 included, the error term for this group is zero because there is only 1 observation and the $h_{ii}$ term in HC3 is then 1 and HC3 cannot be computed.)

Further, I read that HC3 is the default and preferred way. Without x=20 that method works well, with x=20 included it doesn't, which is also a sign that something is problematic with the data. A simulation study shows that HC3 is better than HC1, Look at [this paper](https://jslsoc.sitehost.iu.edu/files_research/testing_tests/hccm/00TAS.pdf).

Finally this. If your goal is to show that the groups do not differ, why then bother about heteroscedasticty if they appear to be equal even with the stronger assumption of homoscedasticity? It can only get less significant with heteroscedasticity I expect, like you do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will need some time to react properly, but I will eventually.