# Regression with single-observation dummies: F-test under heteroskedasticity

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, heteroscedasticity, categorical-encoding, singular-matrix

I have a linear regression model with an intercept and a few dummy variables. Each of the dummies indicate a single observation, so the fit is perfect for these observations. Having fit the model, the usual `summary` command outputs, among other things, the $F$-test of $H_0$ that all of the dummies are jointly zero. This is a hypothesis I am interested in.

Now I suspect some heteroskedasticity (which is not implemented in my simulation but likely is present in the real data I am otherwise working with). I obtain a heteroskedasticity-robust covariance matrix and try to run the same test using `linearHypothesis` from `car`. Unfortunately, I get the following error message:

```r
Error in hccm.lm(model, type = white.adjust) : 
  hccm estimator is singular because of 5 cases with hatvalue = 1:
   96, 97, 98, 99, 100
```

Unsurprisingly, these are the observations associated with the dummies.

**Question:** How may I modify the procedure to obtain the overall $F$-test while accounting for heteroskedasticity? Or is this impossible for my model?

---

Here is the code for replication:

```r
library(car)
n=100; n1=95; n2=n-n1
set.seed(12345); y=rnorm(n)
dummy=c( rep(0,n1), c(1:n2) ); dummy=as.factor(dummy)
m1=lm(y~dummy); summary(m1)
# Allowing for possible heteroskedasticity:
hypo=paste0(rownames(coef(m1))[-1],"=0")
lh1=linearHypothesis(model=m1, hypothesis.matrix=hypo, white.adjust="hc1"); print(lh1)
```

Comment: In a similar vein, see also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/643152